# Capture Ctrl-C Signal And Wait For Subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, signals

I have a bit of python code in which I call a subprocess, and within the python script I want to capture the SIGINT signal, and wait for the subprocess to finish. Currently what I have kills the process when I ctrl-c. Any way to tell python to wait for the process to finish? 
Although I want to wait for the process, I do want the script to die after the process finishes, not sure if theres a way to do this.

```
import subprocess as sp  
from celery.platforms import signals 

def outer_fun(): 
    p = None

    def signal_handler(signum, frame): 
        if p != None: 
            p.wait()

signals['INT'] = signal_handler 

p = sp.Popen(['sleep','30'])
result = p.wait() 

print result[0]

outer_fun()
```

Comment: if you wrap your code in `try/except` and the `except` block specifically calls `KeyboardInterrupt`, you should be able to handle that case

Comment: Calling p.wait() inside the except block still does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, although not what I expected it works! With the preexec_fn=os.setpgrp option the ctrl c signal is not sent to the subprocess.

```
p = sp.Popen(cmd, preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)
```